# javascript element not found

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax

I have an "export to excel" option in my app. When I click that button I am showing a confirmation message to the user. When the user clicks OK, I am calling a click event using JavaScript.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="PagePlaceholder" runat="Server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smMainpage" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div style="text-align: left; font-size: 8pt" id="div5" runat="server">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 50%">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="display: none">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnblkupdate" runat="server" Text="None" OnClick="btnblkupdate_click" />
                                                <div>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnhdnExport" runat="server" OnClick="btnhdnExport_click" /></div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkExport" OnClick="lnkExport_Click" CssClass="customFont" runat="server"
                                                    Text="Export to Excel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnFilter" OnClick="lnkbtnFilter_Click" CssClass="customFont"
                                                    runat="server" Text="Filter Data"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReset" OnClick="lnkReset_Click" Visible="false" CssClass="customFont"
                                                    runat="server" Text="Reset Filter"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnViewAll" OnClick="lnkbtnViewAll_Click" runat="server" Text="View All"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                &nbsp; Selected Records:<asp:Label ID="lblselTsks" Width="20px" Font-Size="10pt"
                                                    Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                Total Records found:&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTotRecCount" Font-Bold="true" runat="server"
                                                    ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="10pt" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkExport" />
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnhdnExport" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress5" EnableViewState="false" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="up"
                DisplayAfter="10" runat="server">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
protected void lnkExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        string strName = string.Empty;
        clsSearch_BL clsObj = new clsSearch_BL();
        //dsResult = (DataSet)Session["SearchRes"];

        if (Session["detObj"] != null)
        {
            DetState detObj = (DetState)Session["detObj"];
            dsResult = clsObj.getSearchResults_BL(detObj);
            HashSet<string> orderIdclmtest = new HashSet<string>();
            int j = dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
               orderIdclmtest.Add( dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[k][1].ToString());
            }
             Session["orderIdclmtest"] = orderIdclmtest.ToString();

            HashSet<string> strtest = new HashSet<string>();
            strtest =(HashSet<string>)Session["orderIdclm"];

            var testttt=strtest.Except(orderIdclmtest).ToList();
            int cnt = testttt.Count;
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                if (str.Length == 0)
                    str.Append(testttt[i]);
                else
                    str.Append(", " + testttt[i]);
            }
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.up, this.GetType(), "export", "hdnExportExcel()", true);
            //if (testttt != null && testttt.Any())
            //{
            //    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.up, this.GetType(), "export", "hdnExportExcel('"+str+"')", true);
            //}
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log.Warn("Logging:" + ex);

    }
    finally {
        if(dsResult != null)
        dsResult.Dispose();
    }
}

function hdnExportExcel() {
if (confirm('You are about to miss the tasks do you want to continue?')) {
    document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_btnhdnExport').click();
}
else {
    return false;
}}
```

My problem is I am getting `document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_btnhdnExport')` is null. But in the page's source I can see the element ID as `ctl00_PagePlaceholder_btnhdnExport`

I don't know why it's not working. I am guessing it's because of postbacktrigger in updatepanel. I tried placing the `btnhdnExport` outside update panel and removed it from triggers Option. But it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the html? I cannot see `ctl00_PagePlaceholder_btnhdnExport` anywhere in asp code

Comment: Lots of questions here.  Why is the containing `<td>` hidden?  Where is the other postback trigger ("lnkExport")?  Most of all, where is hdnExportExcel being called from?  I would expect it to be assigned to btnhdnExport.OnClientClick.  Are you registering it during the AsyncPostback?

Comment: @chprpipr, my requirement is when user clicks export to excel i need to compare my orders on that grid with another list or orders. If any orders missing i need to display message above. If user clicks yes then export else dont. So i made one hidden button, if user clicks yes then calling the hidden button click event using javascript..i didnt post the entire code. The lnkExport is in update panel as well Please see modified code

Answer (score 0):

As Ankur said, your element ID is not accessible at the time that the JavaScript is loaded (page is being created dynamically).

I would recommend changing

`document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_btnhdnExport')`

to

`document.getElementById('btnhdnExport')`

Answer (score 0):

When the UpdatePanel updates, it replaces everything within its container `<div>`.  The button literally doesn't exist at the time your JS code is being called.  One way around this is to use .NET's PageRequestManager to call you JS code after the UpdatePanel is done doing it's thing.  Try something like this:

```
function hdnExportExcel() {

  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  prm.add_pageLoaded(function() {

      if (confirm('You are about to miss the tasks do you want to continue?')) {
          document.getElementById('<%= btnhdnExport.ClientID %>').click();
      }
      else {
          return false;
      }
  }

}
```

You'll notice that I also am not hard coding the button's ID value.  You'll want to avoid hard coding any id values that are being dynamically generated by .NET as they will change when your page's structure changes in the future.  It's no fun making an unrelated change somewhere else on the page and finding out in testing or later that previously solid functionality is now broken.

Comment: Make sure that you javascript block is below the ScriptManager on your aspx page.

Comment: Now I am getting error like ReferenceError: hdnExportExcel is not defined

Comment: Replace your existing code with this: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.up, this.GetType(), "export", "setTimeout(function() { hdnExportExcel(); }, 0)", true);`

Comment: what will happen if i place this code? why i got hdnExportExcel is not defined error before? I just want to know.

Comment: The "hdnExportExcel is not defined" error was generated because at the time the "RegisterClientScriptBlock" code was executed, the hdnExportExcel function hadn't been defined yet (it gets defined a few lines later).  By adding the setTimeout method, hdnExportExcel is "deferred" or run later.  This should cause it to run after hdfExportExcel is defined, thus eliminating the error.